# I get this error "Function name must be a string"

Tags: php

I have a PHP class where one of the private member is a callback to my log function (i.e. in PHP land, a function pointer is simply a string containing the name of the function to call).

```
self::$logferr = "msgfunc";
self::$logferr($res);
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string

`self::$logferr` is equal to `"msgfunc"` which is my log function.

If I rewrite the code like this (on the same very class method):

```
$tmp = "msgfunc";
$tmp($res);
```

It works, the log function get called

Comment: is it possible to see the class?

Comment: Try this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php  ?

Comment: Minimum verifiable example?

Comment: Also, I don't encourage such method calling via string unless you are designing a framework. It creates a lot of confusion while debugging as to what data is being passed around and which method is being called.

Comment: @lighter your solution worked. Please post the answer and I'll upvote it

Comment: @Gianluca Ghettini I post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func`. ref: [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

```
call_user_func(self::$logferr, $res);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap your variable in parenthesis, let PHP resolve the value first:

```
(self::$logferr)($res);
```

[Proof of concept](https://3v4l.org/uQfJ2)

Answer (score 1):

You should call it by using

```
 self::{self::$logferr}($req)
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/CYURS

Answer (score 0):

Let's build a reproducible example:

```
class Foo {

    private static $_loggerCallback;

    static function setLogCallback(callable $loggerCallback) {
        self::$_loggerCallback = $loggerCallback;
    }

    static function log(...$arguments) {
        if (NULL !== self::$_loggerCallback) {
          return self::$_loggerCallback(...$arguments);
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}


Foo::setLogCallback(function() { echo 'success'; } );
Foo::log();
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _loggerCallback in /in/f3stL on line 13

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /in/f3stL:13
```

The notice reports the actual mistake in this case. If you do not get something like it, you should check your error reporting configuration.

The notice shows that PHP looks for a local variable `$_loggerCallback`. It tries to execute `$_loggerCallback(...$arguments)`. Here are different possibilities to make the call explicit.

Use parenthesis (PHP >= 7.0):

```
return (self::$_loggerCallback)(...$arguments);
```

Use a local variable (as you did):

```
$callback = self::$_loggerCallback;
return $callback(...$arguments);
```

A small advise. PHP support anonymous functions. You do not need a (global) function for a callback. This avoids calling to the function by name as well.